# Error while changing paths in MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Hi iam trying to change the path in some links in my WordPress database.

In my table `wp_commeentmeta`, I am using the syntax:

```
UPDATE table SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'http://articles.mydomain.com', 'http://localhost/articles')
```

**BUT I get the following ERROR:**

> ,#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'table SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value,
>   'http://articles.mydomain.com', 'http' at line 1

Any help on this please?

**Please note :** I am using phpMyAdmin for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the table to be the name of your table

```
UPDATE wp_commeentmeta 
SET meta_value = REPLACE(
    meta_value, 
    'http://articles.mydomain.com', 
    'http://localhost/articles'
);
```

(Just fyi, the linebreaks aren't important, just makes the query more readable)